# Connection to other side was lost in a non-clean fashion

Tags: python, scrapy

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class dmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

then I run "scrapy crawl dmoz"
then I got this error:

> 2013-09-14 13:20:56+0700 [dmoz] DEBUG: Retrying http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/>
>   (failed 1 times): Connection to other side was lost in a non-clean
>   fashion.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a web-server or connection problem. Nothing you can do here. Try again later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your internet connection or if you're using proxy, set your environment variables for proxy authentication.

In windows, try these steps:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> type 'systempropertiesadvanced' (without
   quote)
2. Click "Environment Variables..." button
3. Add 2 new variables (either user/system variable is fine):

```
name        | value
------------+--------------------------------  
HTTP_PROXY  | http://username:password@host:port 
HTTPS_PROXY | https://username:password@host:port
```

alternative way: [setting-proxy-env](https://superuser.com/questions/48813/how-to-set-a-proxy-server-for-connecting-to-the-internet-in-lynx)

Comment: thanks for the answer! it works for me!
I didn't notice that my laptop use proxy for connecting to internet!

Comment: What about linux users?

Comment: @AlbertoLópezPérez to set environment variables in linux you can use `export HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@host:port`