# Failed to craw the website using Scrapy: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion

Tags: scrapy

I tried to use scrapy to scrap one website but kept receiving the error "Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion."

Tried to set the user agent and headers but it won't work. The following is the completed log. Any idea will be apprieciated.

http://pastebin.com/CSQ7Dkme

Comment: Did you see this answer by user nametal on here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799140/connection-to-other-side-was-lost-in-a-non-clean-fashion)

Comment: I'm not using proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for this information is that there is a problem with the requested page, not the code.